# Are All the Galaxies in the Universe the Same Age?

Tags: cosmology

Are all the galaxies of the universe the same age?  Or, are some older than others?

Comment: Sometimes galaxies [merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_merger) or [split](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/11330), so you'd presumably say this creates daughter galaxies younger than the rest.

Comment: There's a lot of info on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy) about galaxies. I'd start reading there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of billions of years they are pretty much the same age. Somewhere between 10 to 13 1/2 billion years old on average. Of course there could be younger ones including some that have merged. There are also many that have been disturbed and are in the process of forming again.